# Create Windows 95, 98, 2000, XP NT, 7, 10

Tags: electron

I come across the following link - https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows95

Running windows 95 as Electron APP

1. Is it possible to create any existing application as portable or cross-platform using electron like above?
2. Can we use Windows 7 or 10 like above without Oracle Virtual Box or VM in an existing Windows 8 machine ?

Need more details on how it is possible to bring an application via electron

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm hearing you right, you're wondering if you can put a whole OS into a JS VM running in Electron - and then run your app on top of that.

Please don't do that. Electron is a fantastic cross-platform solution, but my project `windows95` was mostly an educational experiment showcasing how powerful modern JavaScript and Electron can be.

Answer (score 1):

This project uses another project called [v86](https://github.com/copy/v86/), which is capable of virtualising a x86 platform and display its output on a HTML element. Electron is browser-based so that is why this works.

But there are some limitations: It virtualises the x86 platform, which is pretty old by now, and when you have a look at the specification, it says it is at a Pentium-1 state. The demo links on the project's GitHub ReadMe also do not contain any "modern" OS because v86 does not support SSE(2). And since Microsoft [requires its users to have a SSE2-compatible CPU](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4088875/windows-7-update-kb4088875)* it is not possible to run anything like Windows 7 or newer (Linux ***may*** work, anyway).

OSses which support this kind of (deprecated) hardware, ***may*** work. As you can see from the "Compatibility" section of the project's ReadMe, some Linux versions and Windows XP "work" but older software, like OS/2, and even newer stuff, like Android, don't (really). So you can't say that everything will work as expected because the execution environment is really limited.

Now to answer your first point, no, I don't think that you can wrap every existing app into an Electron application and run it on new hardware. It ***may*** work with old software (which do not require SSE, if you use v86, and that would require a lot of hackery on the v86 side because it is designed to run OSses), but don't quote me on that.

---

`*` The section in question reads (at the time of writing) like this:

> A Stop error occurs on computers that don't support Streaming Single Instructions Multiple Data (SIMD) Extensions 2 (SSE2).
>
> Upgrade your machines with a **processor that supports SSE2** or virtualize those machines.

(emphasis mine, source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4088875/windows-7-update-kb4088875)